# Double dispatch in Java

Tags: java, polymorphism, object-reference, double-dispatch

I am not sure if i have wrong idea about double dispatch. But this is what i thought:

```
class A{
   void testA( B obj ){
         System.out.println( "A-Parent" );
          obj.testB();
   }
}


class AChild extends A{
   void testA( B obj ){
         System.out.println( "A-Child" );
         obj.testB();
   }
}


class B{
   void testB(){
         System.out.println( "B-Parent" );
   }
}


class BChild extends B{
   void testB(){
         System.out.println( "B-Child" );
   }
}

class Launcher{
  public static void main(){
  A objA = new AChild();
  B objB = new BChild();

  objA.testA(objB);
  }
}

What I expected:

A-Child
B-Parent

Actual output:

A-Child
B-Child   // How ???????
```

I thought Java resolves objA to Achild correctly during run time while the parameter is resolved during compile time to B, due to Javas Single diapatch. please tell me where i got it wrong?

Comment: changed, perils of writing code in notepad :)

Comment: consider changing your main method also.. !!!

Comment: Found the issue here. I thought since the arguments are statically resolved the resulting method will use the method defined in the resolved class. but java always resolves the receiver object at runtime. http://java.dzone.com/articles/multiple-dispatch-fix-some

Answer (score 1):

Don't see reason why **'B-Parent'** should be printed instead of **'B-Child'**

```
     B objB = new BChild();
     objA.testA(objB);
```

**objB** actually have an instance of child of B. So **B-Child** will get printed. So this is run time binding or Polymorphism feature of Java in action :)

Answer (score -3):

you need to use the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern to implement double dispatch in java.

Comment: I understand that visitor pattern is a hack to support double dispatch in java. My question is about double dispatch and the way java handles the scenario. thanks for the comment.